# how to add custom UIView in scnview of arkit?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I want to add `'UIview'` in the *scnview of arkit*.
How to create a node of `UIView` to add my `uiview` in the `addchildnode()` of `scnview`?

Answer (score 2):

You can now. It’s possible to add a `UIView` as an `SCNMaterialProperty`.

See the following post how to do so;
[Using a UIView in 3D in Scenekit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425281/uiview-as-scnmaterialproperty-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

ARKit isn't a rendering engine — it doesn't display any content for you. ARKit provides information about real-world spaces for use by rendering engines such as SceneKit, Unity, and any custom engine you build (with Metal, etc).

SceneKit can't render a UIView as part of a 3D scene. But it can render planes, cubes, or other shapes, and texture-map 2D content onto them. If you want to draw a text label on a plane detected by ARKit, that's the direction to investigate — follow the example's, um, example to create SCNPlane objects corresponding to detected ARPlaneAnchors, get yourself an image of some text.