# UIView as SCNMaterialProperty on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, scenekit

When using a `UIView` as an `SCNMaterialProperty` in a SceneKit scene, can that view be part of the responder chain?

To clarify how:

```
omg_you_can_use_an_actual_uiview_now = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
material_plane.diffuse.contents = omg_you_can_use_an_actual_uiview_now
let geom_plane = SCNPlane(width: 1, height: 1)
geom_plane.materials = [material_plane]
```

Comment: Nice! But my viewcontroller life cicle does not start, so any view load, just an empty view, any idea?

Comment: Does this work with layers ? i.e. if you add a cornerRadius to the layer of the view ?